# Express.js live variable injection into HTML files?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

Say I have a variable:

```
var n = 3
```

Say this variable is set in an app running a standard express.js server with the following endpoint:

```
var express = require(‘express.js’);
var app = express()

var n = 3

app.get(‘/‘, function(req,res) {
res.sendFile(__dirname + ‘/index.html’)
app.listen(3000)
```

Is there anyway I can inject the contents of `n` into index.html?

Comment: Please, try to elaborate more on your problem, it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I have edited t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a template rendering engine, such as [handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hbs).  There are many other choices, but handlebars will work for your case.

A template rendering engine will take a template file, and an object with passed-in values, and render it to HTML:

Add handlebars to your project with npm:

```
npm install hbs
```

in app.js

```
var express = require(‘express.js’);
var app = express()
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

var n = 3

app.get(‘/‘, function(req,res) {
  res.render('index', {n: n})
}
app.listen(3000)
```

Move `index.html` to `views/index.hbs`, and use the passed in value like this::

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>The value of n is {{n}}</p>
  </body>
</html>
```